# How do I build my LEGO slope so it connects to the flat top without any notable ridges?

Tags: technic, building, moc

I'm currently building a functional LEGO escalator that is minifigure-scaled and with staircases transitioning from flat platform to stairwell to flat platform. Here's my progress so far:
[image: 39.5 LEGO slope with Technic frame (green) and top for flat transition (yellow)]
Here's the stair design I use for this escalator:
[image: stair design]

Now that I have clearly defined the necessary framework for the slope, I am currently working on the escalator's flat top (yellow). However, I couldn't come up with any designs for getting the flat top to "connect" to the slope without any ridges or gaps that could catch the stair's shafts.

My ideal result should resemble this design, with the slope still retain a 39.5 degree angle and the top has to be flat:
[image: ideal result]

Ideally, this build should utilize legal techniques for ensuring stability due to its technic nature.

I want to create an escalator like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VAjFw7v8QhE) but at a minifigure scale, therefore I don't intend to use LEGO's [dedicated escalator piece](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=69900).

Bricklink and any Pick-A-Brick retailers of similar fashion are not locally available for me, and I don't have the necessary bricks at my disposal, so therefore I couldn't physically test out my builds.

Comment: "I don't intend to use Lego's dedicated escalator piece." I didn't know there's such a thing. Which part do you mean by that?

Comment: @zovits [this piece](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=69900#T=P&C=86), mentioned in OP's previous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update on my query: I've figured out a design that can reasonably get the slope to connect to the flat top with as little ridge as possible: using a 1x2x1 panel to extend the brick slope using a SNOT bracket, and fitted with a cheese slope wedge on the flat top also with a SNOT bracket. Here are the Stud.io renditions of the design: [image: Stud.io rendition] [image: Stud.io rendition, profile]

As far as Stud.io and the real model shows, this seems to be a legal building technique. However I am still not sure, as the slope might induce stress on the slope.